# How to run Database Triggers without visiting the URL link returned by the Deploy command

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I tried to do my first project on Google Cloud Functions.
I tried the code provided by google :

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();

// Take the text parameter passed to this HTTP endpoint and insert it into
// Cloud Firestore under the path /messages/:documentId/original
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  // Grab the text parameter.
  const original = req.query.text;
 // Push the new message into Cloud Firestore using the Firebase Admin SDK.
  const writeResult = await admin
  .firestore()
  .collection("messages")
  .add({ original: original });
// Send back a message that we've succesfully written the message
  res.json({ result: `Message with ID: ${writeResult.id} added.` });
});
```

Everything is working fine as expect.
But, I have to visit the url returned by the command:

`$ firebase deploy --only functions`

It returns me a url that i must visit to run the function.
My question is: for Database Triggers, do I have to open the url through the browser to execute the functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For Database Triggers, do I have to open the url through the browser
> to execute the functions?

No, for database triggers (Firestore or the Realtime Database), which are background triggers, you don't need to call an URL: the Cloud Function is triggered accordingly to the handler used to define the Function (e.g. `onCreate()`, `onUpdate()`, etc. for [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#function_triggers) or `onWrite()`, `onCreate()`, etc. for the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#trigger_a_function)).

There is actually no URL available for background triggered Cloud Functions.

Comment: I define a Trigger and I deploy. firebase Cloud Functions will run on its own. it's like that ?

Comment: Yes, as soon as an event corresponding to the trigger type occurs, the Cloud Function runs. For example, if your Cloud Function for Firestore is `exports.myFunction = functions.firestore.document('my-collection/{doc-id}').onCreate((change, context) => { /* ... */ });`
, as soon as a document is created in the `my-collection` the Cloud Function runs. And this is the case whatever is the way the document was created: through a Client SDK, the Firestore console, via the REST API, etc...